# unordered sampling without replacement

Tags: combinatorics, sampling

Is my reasoning correct?

Original Problem Question:

> A group of $6$ students is chosen from a list of $5$ math students and $4$ phycology students. What is the probability that $4$ math students and $2$ physke students are chosen?

My attempt:
$$\frac{{5\choose4}{4\choose2}}{{11\choose6}} = \frac{5}{77}$$

Comment: Where does the $11$ come from?  There are $9$ students all in all...

Comment: ohh its 9 choose 6 at the bottom, so its equal to 5/14. Thanks dumb mistake